# FlatFileParseException Parsing error - Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I follow this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) and I'm getting `FlatFileParseException` error:

> org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing
>   error at line: 1 in resource=[class path resource [country.csv]],
>   input=[AA,Aruba]

`country.csv`

```
AA,Aruba
BB,Baruba
```

and here is my `ItemReader` method

```
@Bean
    public ItemReader<Country> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Country> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Country>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("country.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Country>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[] { "countryCode", "countryName" });
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Country>() {{
                setTargetType(Country.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }
```

and `Country.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Country")
public class Country  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "countryCode", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    String countryCode;

    @Column(name = "countryName", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    String countryName;

    public Country(String countryCode, String countryName) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.countryName = countryName;

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "countryCode: " + countryCode + ", countryName: " + countryName;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post full stacktrace; but I will start with empty-ctor for `Country` and  setters for `countryName`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem here is that you are missing a default no-arg constructor in your `Country` class.

You are using [`BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.html) to map a [`FieldSet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/FieldSet.html) to an object. Quoting the [`setTargetType(type)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.html#setTargetType-java.lang.Class-) Javadoc:

> An object of this type will be created from its default constructor for every call to `mapFieldSet(FieldSet)`.

As such, you need to add a default constructor and provide the corresponding getter / setter for the properties.